# Cyclisation reaction through hydrazine

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, carbonyl-compounds

The following reaction confuses me - I don't understand how and why it happened (couldn't figure out the mechanism):

[image]

I thought this is some Wolff Kishner sort of reduction, but the reagents don't match (no alkaline medium). I am not sure how hydrazine lead to cyclisation - for starters, I guess it added to the carbonyl oxygen (aldehyde, as it is more reactive) as an ammonia derivative to form a hydrazone. What's next?

Comment: What's next in a further nucleophilic attack by the NH2 at the other end of the  hydrazone on the ketone

Comment: I did that, what happens then?

Comment: Elimination of water to form the product drawn

Comment: Could you please add the mechanism as an answer? I'm not able to figure out how dehydration would occur after internal nucleophilic attack by the nitrogen on carbonyl oxygen. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's essentially just the same reaction once and then over again. The basic medium of the Wolf-Kishner reduction is to remove the hydrazone hydrogen, releasing the $\ce{C=N}$ electrons onto the carbon. In this reaction, the hydrazone instead further reacts with the other carbonyl to form an aromatic 6-membered ring.

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]

[image: step 3]

[image: step 4]

[image: step 5]